# Viewing Mac Localhost on a network PC

Tags: macos, networking, localhost, lamp, sharing

I am developing some websites on my Mac (Standard LAMP setup, with PHP5, Using Remy Sharp's LAMP setup instructions). I can see these sites locally by going to (eg http:// apple.dev).

I was just wondering how I view these sites on a connected network PC.

I have tried:
http:// MY-IP-ADDRESS/~MYUSERNAME/apple.dev

But this just returns the file directory structure for the website.

I can see the default webpage by just going to:
http:// MY-IP-ADDRESS/~MYUSERNAME/

Am I doing anything wrong or do I need to do anything else?

I have enabled web sharing

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with that tutorial or setup but this is an apache configuration issue. You need to configure apache to serve the site at http://MY-IP-ADDRESS/WhateverYouWant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a server alias setup for this site already. In which case the answer is pretty simple. Just edit the hosts file on your pc and enter the ip of your pc together with the server alias in the usual fashion, e.g.

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xx  apple.dev
```

Where xxx.xxx.xx.xx = your mac's ip address, as found in web sharing.

If this is done, then your pc should find the site when you browse to that alias in its web browser.